# What is a bandwidth efficient way to query Microsoft SQL Server to find a unique row where ID exists in Foreign Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

Sorry if I have not worded the question well. I thought about it for a few minutes and this is the best I could come up with.

Long story short, I am adding some Audit Logging into my software (.NET) and am looking for the most efficient way to find out if any modifications were made.

My structure is I have a data object, lets call it a **UserLogon**, which contains the timestamp, username and access level of somebody logging in to the program.

Now, I have a table of **Changesets** where one record is created whenever somebody changes the details of the UserLogon.  Eg - I logged on as the wrong User, so a data validation person has gone into the event editing system and changed the history for me.

So, there might be 5 different changesets tagged onto the User Logon.

**All I want to ask of SQL is for it to tell me True or False that there is at least 1 Changeset linked to the UserLogon.**

Currently I have a Join

```
SELECT Event.Id, Changeset.Id AS ChangesetId 
FROM Event 
LEFT JOIN Changeset 
ON Event.Id = Changeset.EventId 
WHERE Changeset.EventId = Event.Id
```

Which produces the following

```
Id  ChangesetId
F12E54FE-72DF-4A3B-B61B-A4DD00F02597    FA2E0EEB-E5FA-41D1-8C61-A4DD00F025A0
7D1372A2-AE4A-4BB9-9800-A4DE00BB1527    FC2496DC-9DF7-4C47-959A-A4DE00BB153C
7D1372A2-AE4A-4BB9-9800-A4DE00BB1527    F0CB41F3-D8E3-40F2-B3CE-A4DF00918478
7D1372A2-AE4A-4BB9-9800-A4DE00BB1527    4E974BB8-CB41-49E4-A2E7-A4DF00951AE4
7D1372A2-AE4A-4BB9-9800-A4DE00BB1527    2887ACBB-4032-4BDD-B8EF-A4E400BD5385
7D1372A2-AE4A-4BB9-9800-A4DE00BB1527    8BC5CC13-F557-42FA-9A50-A4E400D370AC
```

So we can see here there are 2 UserLogons, but there are 5 ChangeSets for the second one.

I would ultimately like to end up with just a True/False on the second column but not too sure where to go from here, or if thats even possible.

My intention is to use this to display an Icon on a ListView in WPF for modified rows to show the user if the row is original or altered.

Comment: You should decide on the database you are using and tag the question appropriately..

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff, I just went with suggested tags and didnt pay much attention there.

Comment: . . I don't know why Stack Overflow recommends "mysql" when the question has a portion that looks like SQL.  The appropriate tagging would be "sql" along with the database being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select e.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from ChangeSet cs where cs.EventId = e.EventId)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as HasChangesetFlag
from event e;
```

For performance, you want an index on `ChangeSet(EventId)`.

Note:  This is ANSI SQL and should work in almost any database.